# Error when running emulator: Not enough disk space to run AVD

Tags: android, debian, android-virtual-device

I get the following error message when trying to run the emulator from Android Studio:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough disk space to run AVD 'Nexus_6_API_28'. Exiting...

I tried to increase the size of RAM space but it didn't help.

Software: Debian, Android studio virtual device.

[device settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIw4y.png)
[df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFEjy.png)

Comment: Look for c:\users\<username>\.android\.avd folder. If you are creating avd over and over data of avd or deleted avd still exists here.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The issue is not with the amount on your hard drive but the setting requesting how much storage space is required by the emulator.

In Android Studio, follow these steps to reduce the hard drive space requested by the emulator:

1. Click **Tools** -> **AVD Manager**
2. Click the edit icon for the emulator
3. Click the **Show Advanced Settings**
4. Under **Memory and Storage**, reduce the **Internal Storage**, specify something like 2048MB for an emulator that comes with Google Play store or less for emulators without the Google Play Store.

Try to run again and see if it works.

If the above doesn't work, try wiping out the user data from the emulator. You can wipe the user data from the actions sections on the AVD Manager screen.

[image: AVD Manager Internal Storage Setting]

Comment: Wiping data was important

Comment: Wiping data did the trick!

Answer (score 16):

It's not about `RAM`, if you are beginner just use the recomended amount of `RAM` when creating new `AVD`. In order to solve your particular problem, Go to the disc where is stored your `AVD` files, mine is in this `Path`:

> E:\avd.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_27_1.avd

and free up some space on that hard drive. Do not delete anything from avd folder ! If you do not know on which hard drive is stored your AVD files, go to `Tools->AVD Manager`

[image: AVD Manager]
Choose your emulator and in it's drop-down list press the `Show on Disc` button. It will take you to that hard drive, then just free up some space. Not sure about minimum space, I have `20Gb` and it works perfectly, you can start from minimum 5Gb. Also in that drop-down list try to `Wipe the Data` first and run the app,  before trying to do all mentioned above.

Comment: trying `Wipe data` option helped me. Wiping data significantly reduced the size on disk. But it will delete the previously installed apps and the configuration settings on your emulator

Comment: Adaptation of this answer to Linux: "Show on Disk" is actually useful, because it will show which partition is incriminated for lack of space, and which dir there should be moved to another partition with more available space, then symlinked back to its original space

Answer (score 7):

Just follow below steps

```
1 Increases the size of Internal Storage in AVD
2 Free the C drive in your computer at lease 5-10 GB.
```

The Emulator will run automatically. Hope it helps

Comment: I checked that my C folder has only 288MB left. Oh, I just removed trash bin and Temp folder to get my space back.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the same problem by delete some virtual device from AVD and it's work well

Answer (score 2):

A more **stable** and reliable solution is to change your **AVD path** to another hard drive because the default AVD path is always on main drive, can be easily
done:

[Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nDslqV9zrK4)

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer:

Delete your AVD and recreate a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all the virtual devices from Avd manager, and installing required ones helped me. Although I followed all the above mentioned steps one by one. I advice you guys to try this out if nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Event Log of your Android Studio. It might tell you the exact reason. In my case it said

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Not enough space to create userdata
> partition. Available: 5753.562500 MB at
> /home/xxxxxxx/.android/avd/Pixel_3_API_30.avd, need 7372.800000 MB.

So I freed up some space, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

just free some space in the hard disk for the emultor internal storage.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wiping data of emulator is working.